# How to get the equation of polynomial model in R?

Tags: r, regression, polynomials

I am trying to fit a multivariate Polynomial Regression in R using 5 independent variables. I am using the following code

```
#Generate some data
df <- subset(mtcars, select = c(mpg, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec))

#Fit multivariate Polynomial Regression in R
ploy_reg <- lm(mpg ~ polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec,
                          degree=2, raw=TRUE), data = df)

summary(ploy_reg)
```

Now if you see the output, it is very hard to generate the model equation

```
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, 
    raw = TRUE), data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.7134 -0.9183 -0.0593  0.8730  3.7362 

Coefficients:
                                                                   Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                                                      -1.320e+02  4.772e+02  -0.277
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)1.0.0.0.0  3.381e-01  8.146e-01   0.415
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)2.0.0.0.0  5.522e-04  4.014e-04   1.376
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.1.0.0.0  2.575e-02  1.130e+00   0.023
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)1.1.0.0.0 -2.318e-04  9.287e-04  -0.250
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.2.0.0.0 -3.833e-04  7.469e-04  -0.513
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.1.0.0  8.239e+01  1.126e+02   0.732
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)1.0.1.0.0 -4.733e-02  9.809e-02  -0.483
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.1.1.0.0  4.463e-02  1.362e-01   0.328
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.2.0.0 -7.873e+00  7.553e+00  -1.042
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.0.1.0 -2.580e+01  7.072e+01  -0.365
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)1.0.0.1.0 -1.625e-01  8.481e-02  -1.916
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.1.0.1.0  1.435e-01  1.285e-01   1.117
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.1.1.0 -4.472e+00  7.299e+00  -0.613
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.0.2.0  7.614e+00  5.214e+00   1.460
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.0.0.1  2.376e+00  2.639e+01   0.090
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)1.0.0.0.1  6.842e-03  3.138e-02   0.218
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.1.0.0.1 -2.991e-02  4.645e-02  -0.644
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.1.0.1 -5.645e-01  3.419e+00  -0.165
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.0.1.1  3.352e-01  3.830e+00   0.088
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.0.0.2  2.492e-02  5.171e-01   0.048
                                                                 Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)                                                        0.7872  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)1.0.0.0.0   0.6861  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)2.0.0.0.0   0.1963  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.1.0.0.0   0.9822  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)1.1.0.0.0   0.8075  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.2.0.0.0   0.6180  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.1.0.0   0.4796  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)1.0.1.0.0   0.6389  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.1.1.0.0   0.7493  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.2.0.0   0.3196  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.0.1.0   0.7222  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)1.0.0.1.0   0.0816 .
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.1.0.1.0   0.2879  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.1.1.0   0.5525  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.0.2.0   0.1722  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.0.0.1   0.9299  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)1.0.0.0.1   0.8314  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.1.0.0.1   0.5328  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.1.0.1   0.8718  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.0.1.1   0.9318  
polym(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)0.0.0.0.2   0.9624  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.519 on 11 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.938, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8253 
F-statistic: 8.322 on 20 and 11 DF,  p-value: 0.0004512
```

Can anyone help me out to interpret model equation?

Comment: looking at the pvalue column it seems most of the predictors used in the model are not significant given to your `mpg` outcome

Comment: Just for example, I have used this dataset. I am having a different dataset.

Comment: you can show your actual datasets

Comment: Maybe with the help of the [equatiomatic](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/equatiomatic/versions/0.3.1) package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **equatiomatic** package (currently on Github only).

```r
library(equatiomatic)

#Generate some data
df <- subset(mtcars, select = c(mpg, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec))

#Fit multivariate Polynomial Regression in R
poly_reg <- lm(mpg ~ poly(disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec,
                           degree=2, raw=TRUE), data = df)

extract_eq(poly_reg, use_coefs = TRUE, wrap = TRUE, terms_per_line = 1)
```

This generates some LaTeX code representing the fitted model.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{\widehat{mpg}} &= -132.02\ + \\
&\quad 0.34(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^1.0.0.0.0})\ + \\
&\quad 0(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^2.0.0.0.0})\ + \\
&\quad 0.03(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^0.1.0.0.0})\ + \\
&\quad 0(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^1.1.0.0.0})\ + \\
&\quad 0(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^0.2.0.0.0})\ + \\
&\quad 82.39(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^0.0.1.0.0})\ - \\
&\quad 0.05(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^1.0.1.0.0})\ + \\
&\quad 0.04(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^0.1.1.0.0})\ - \\
&\quad 7.87(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^0.0.2.0.0})\ - \\
&\quad 25.8(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^0.0.0.1.0})\ - \\
&\quad 0.16(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^1.0.0.1.0})\ + \\
&\quad 0.14(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^0.1.0.1.0})\ - \\
&\quad 4.47(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^0.0.1.1.0})\ + \\
&\quad 7.61(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^0.0.0.2.0})\ + \\
&\quad 2.38(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^0.0.0.0.1})\ + \\
&\quad 0.01(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^1.0.0.0.1})\ - \\
&\quad 0.03(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^0.1.0.0.1})\ - \\
&\quad 0.56(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^0.0.1.0.1})\ + \\
&\quad 0.34(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^0.0.0.1.1})\ + \\
&\quad 0.02(\operatorname{disp,\ hp,\ drat,\ wt,\ qsec,\ degree\ =\ 2^0.0.0.0.2})
\end{aligned}
$$

\end{document}
```

[image]